# How to delete row if the data matches in list using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My `df` is an hourly dataset given below:

```
time                    Open
2017-01-01 00:00:00     5.2475
2017-01-01 01:00:00     5.2180
2017-01-01 02:00:00     5.2128
...., ....
2017-12-31 23:00:00     5.7388
```

I want to delete/remove the `row` if it matches the `Date` `Series` in this list:

```
remove = ['2017-01-01','2017-05-21', '2017-09-19']
```

Please note that the data in `remove` is a single `Day` whereas the data in `df` is `hourly`.

I want to remove any `hourly` data that matches the `Day` in `remove`

**What did I do?**

1: I tried `df2 = df[~df.time.str.startswith(remove)]` but it does not work and gives me float point error.

2: I also tried `df2 = df[~df.time.isin(a)]` but it only removes if it matches entirely not partially.

Could you please help me solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
df2 = df[~df.time.dt.normalize().isin(remove)]
```

`.normalize` removes the time element of your data so you can match against the dates.

```
print(df2)


  time  Open
4   2017-12-31 23:00:00     5.7388
```